# how to do a has_many relation on two tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm trying to do a has_many relation with a table on creation and also to add it in another table already created.

I have my `User` table already with no relations.

I want to create a `Pro_user` with a relation has_many `User`.

The thing is that one `User` can have multiple `Pro_user` and a `Pro_user` can also also have multiple `User`.

So both tables need a `has_many` right ?

So what I thought of was that

`rails g model pro_user name:string email:string password_digest:string user:references`

But this is not the right thing, it's doing a `belongs_to` from `Pro_user` to `User`

And also how should I do to do add the has_many on my existing table `User` ? Do I have to do a migration to recreate the table and adding the relation ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended approach for a many to many association is the "`has_many_through`" approach.  This allows you to add additional columns later on to the join table if you need more data.  You'll need a join table that will at the least  have two reference columns to your Users and ProUsers tables along with the standard id column. 
(Refer to: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

So your User and ProUser tables will not have any reference columns in them.  Instead you'll make a third table called BoatsAndPros (call it whatever you like) and do:

```
    create_table :boats_and_pros do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.belongs_to :pro_user, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
```

Then in the corresponding boats_and_pros.rb Model file you'll add:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :pro_user
```

In your `user.rb` file you'll add:

```
 has_many :boats_and_pros
 has_many :pro_users, through: :boats_and_pros
```

In your `pro_user.rb` model file you'll add

```
has_many :boats_and_pros
has_many :users, through: :boats_and_pros
```

Two key takeaways are:

- The "oldschool" `has_and_belongs_to_many` approach is still fine however doesn't allow room to grow like the has_many_through approach here and you'll need to specifically name the table pro_users_users because Rails expects the two tables to be listed in lexical order.
- One-to-many relationships like what you ended up with on your original attempt keep the reference in one of the tables while many-to-many relationships require a third join table as shown above.