# How Do I Use A Join Table in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have users and books. It's a many to many relationship, so I created a join table based on questions and answers I found on this site.

```
 class Book < ApplicationRecord
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
 end

 class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_and_belongs_to_many :books
 end

 class BooksUsersJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
   def change
    create_table :books_users_join_table, :id => false do |t|
        t.integer :book_id, index: false
        t.integer :user_id, index: false
    end
  end

  add_index(:books_users, [:book_id, :user_id], :unique => true)
  add_index(:books_users, :book_id)
  add_index(:books_users, :user_id)
 end
```

So I suppose my questions are:

1. Will this join_table work how I have it or is there a better way to have written it?
2. I just wrote the add_index lines in this file. Do I have to create indexes from the command line and if so, how do I do that?
3. How do I use this join_table in a controller?

Comment: Check my answer here for questions 1 & 3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43590522/how-to-do-a-has-many-relation-on-two-tables/43590819#43590819   It explains the difference between has_many_through and many_to_many and how to use them.  For question 2, your fine doing indexes like that and don't need a separate migration file.

Comment: ok, so using has_many_through, how would I create a relationship between user and book in a controller? like book_users_table.new(book_id, user_id)?

Comment: You would do book.users.build(user_params_here).  Then call book.save  (You should also add to your models accepts_nested_attributes_for :users and accepts_nested_attributes_for :books)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use do a join

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @books Book.all.joins(:user)
  end
end
```

I hope that this helps